# Google Play Music Gapless playback on web app?

Tags: google-play-music

I read that Google had added gapless playback a while back, in apps. I don't use the service on my phone or iPad nearly as often as I stream from my desktop where my good sound system is. So far though, I've seen no way to get a gapless playback mode.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get gapless playback on the web version?

Answer (score 1):

Currently (November 2015), the web player does not support gapless playback, as frustrating as it may be. However, Google has been gradually adding such a feature to different players, so it may only be a matter of time. (It also may help that many people have been asking for gapless playback on the web.)

Just two months ago, gapless playback was added to the Chromecast player. If you have a TV or other monitor with decent speakers or, better yet, a 5.1 sound system, as well as a Chromecast (which is only US$35), that would be a viable alternative for the meantime. (The Chromecast player can be controlled using the mobile app or the web player.)